# What is wrong with my selection algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm

[image]

So I spent a week on this, and asked my peers, but we couldn't get it right. I turned it in as is, just to be transparent. I just want to know my flaws and mistakes, and understand why this isn't working. I tried my best, and traced it, but the deeper the recursion gets, the more confused I get. Hopefully someone with better insight than I do can help me.

Also, I know this code isn't the best. I was taking baby steps, and I just wanted to get it to work before I optimize it.

My code:

```
public static int select(int[] array, int left, int right, int k) {

    if( array.length <= 1 ) {
        return array[0];
    }
    double proccessedLength = (right-left)+1; // The part of the array we're working with
    int numberOfGroups = (int) proccessedLength/5;
    if( ((double)proccessedLength%5) > 0 ) {
        numberOfGroups++;
    }
    int numberOfRemainders = (int) (proccessedLength%5);
    int[] mediansOfEachGroup = new int[numberOfGroups];

    // Finds the medians of the input array
    for(int x = 0; x < numberOfGroups; x++ ) {
        if( (numberOfRemainders > 0) && x==(numberOfGroups-1)) { // Last Remainder group
            int[] tempArrayForInsertionSorting = new int[numberOfRemainders]; 
            int start=(int) (left+proccessedLength-numberOfRemainders);
            System.out.println(numberOfRemainders);
            for(int y=0; y < numberOfRemainders; y++ ) {
                tempArrayForInsertionSorting[y] = array[start];
                start++;
            }
            int[] sortedTempArray = insertionSort(tempArrayForInsertionSorting,tempArrayForInsertionSorting.length-1);
            if( numberOfRemainders%2 == 0 ) {
                mediansOfEachGroup[numberOfGroups-1] = sortedTempArray[(numberOfRemainders/2)-1];
            } else {
                mediansOfEachGroup[numberOfGroups-1] = sortedTempArray[(int)numberOfRemainders/3];
            }
        } else { // Groups of 5
            int[] tempArrayForInsertionSorting = new int[5];
            int start=left+(x*5);
            for(int y=0; y < 5; y++ ) {
                tempArrayForInsertionSorting[y] = array[start];
                start++;
            }
            int[] sortedTempArray = insertionSort(tempArrayForInsertionSorting,tempArrayForInsertionSorting.length-1);
            mediansOfEachGroup[x] = sortedTempArray[2];
        }
    }


    int medianOfMedians = select(mediansOfEachGroup, left, mediansOfEachGroup.length-1, (int) mediansOfEachGroup.length/2);

    int[] arrayCopyForPartition = new int[array.length];
    System.arraycopy(array,0,arrayCopyForPartition,0,array.length);
    int positionOfMedianOfMedians = partitionForSelect(arrayCopyForPartition, left, right, medianOfMedians);



    if( positionOfMedianOfMedians == k ) {
        return medianOfMedians;
    } else if( positionOfMedianOfMedians < k ){
        return select( array, left, k+1, positionOfMedianOfMedians);
    } else {
        return select( array, k, right, positionOfMedianOfMedians-k);
    }
}

public static void insertionSort(int array[], int n) {
    for (int x = 1; x < n; x++){
        int y = x;
        int temp = array[x];
        while ( (y > 0 ) && (array[y-1] > temp)){
            array[y] = array[y-1];
            y--;
        }
        array[y] = temp;
    }
}

public static int partitionForSelect(int anArray[], int left, int right, int pivot) {
    int x = pivot;
    int i = left-1; 

    for(int j = left; j < right; j++ ) {
        comparisons++;
        if(anArray[j] <= x) {
             i = i + 1;
             int temp =  anArray[i];
             anArray[i] = anArray[j];
             anArray[j] = temp;
        }

    }


    return i+1;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the kind of problem where [unit tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_test) are really useful. Write them first for your `insertionSort()` and `partitionForSelect()` and when you're sure those work correctly, for `select()`. For each method, write several tests that cover different cases, starting with very small arrays and then some differnt larger test cases.

The most important benefit is that when you find a problem in the algorithm and fix it, you will immediately know if it now breaks for some other case.

Another thing that helps is addding [asserts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assert#Assertions_for_run-time_checking) to check [invariants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_%28computer_science%29) and intermediate results.

Comment: I am actually using JUnit. My insertion is working, and my partition is working. I'll double check again.

Comment: @Doug: see if you can add more corner cases to the tests, and start testing select() itself with very simple cases. The asserts might also help.

Comment: I have asserts for my insertion, partition, and select. I am passing the insertion and partition but not select. My sample array size is 10.

Comment: Moreover, your `select` method is very large and complex. Break this up in to many simple well named methods, each with several tests _proving_ to yourself that they work as expected. A good start is to extract the sections you've named with comments into their own methods.